# Is it possible in Python to have the program run with certain group permissions

Tags: python, linux, file, permissions

Basically, I want to run my program such that all the new files and folders it creates belong to a certain group. I know that I can set default file permisions using `os.umask`, but is there also a way to set the group, such that all files and folders created by the program are automatically created to be owned by that group.

Comment: Do you mean without changing the group of the current process?

Comment: @ekhumoro Changing the group of the current process is allowed.

Comment: It's only allowed if the process has the necessary permissions to use `os.setuid`, `os.setgid`, etc.

Comment: Yes I have the permission to use os.setgid.

Comment: So your program is run with root privileges? If so, I don't see what your problem is...

Comment: Not with root priveleges, but I am part of the group which I want to set with os.setgid.

Comment: You must have root privileges to use `os.setgid`.

Comment: I think you are right, because its not working as it is.